# Ruby / Replace value in array of hash

Tags: ruby

How do I replace age with 31?

```
[{"name"=>"Bob"}, {"age"=>"30"}]
```

Comment: If Bob is 30, the attributes should be in the _same_ hash, since they represent the same person: `[{"name"=>"Bob", "age"=>"30"}]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another way, using find

```
1.9.3p194 :007 > array1 = [{"name"=>"Bob"}, {"age"=>"30"}]
 => [{"name"=>"Bob"}, {"age"=>"30"}] 
1.9.3p194 :008 > hash1 = array1.find { |h| h['age'] == "30" }
 => {"age"=>"30"} 
1.9.3p194 :009 > hash1['age'] = 31
 => 31 
1.9.3p194 :010 > array1
 => [{"name"=>"Bob"}, {"age"=>31}]
```

Answer (score 9):

using map! (will replace age value in all hashes that contain it)

```
a = [{"name"=>"Bob"}, {"age"=>"30"}]
a.map! do |h|
  h['age'] = 31 if h['age']
  h
end
a
=> [{"name"=>"Bob"}, {"age"=>31}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not convert the array into something easier and more flexible to work with?  Your array is crying out to be a value object:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :age
  def initialize arr
    arr.each { |h| h.each { |k,v| instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) } }
  end
  def to_hash_array
    instance_variables.each_with_object([]) do |iv, arr|
      arr << {iv.to_s.sub('@','') => instance_variable_get(iv)}
    end
  end
end

def hash_array_to_person arr
  person = Person.new
  arr.each { |h| h.each { |k,v| person.send("#{k}=", v) } }
  person
end

example = [{"name"=>"Bob"}, {"age"=>"30"}]
bob = Person.new(example)

p bob
p bob.to_hash_array
bob.age = 31
p bob.to_hash_array
```

Output:

```
#<Person:0x00000000fe8418 @name="Bob", @age="30">
[{"name"=>"Bob"}, {"age"=>"30"}]
[{"name"=>"Bob"}, {"age"=>31}]
```

Ruby isn't C, you have so much more available to you than the basic primitive data types.

Answer (score 2):

Since what you really have is an array of hashes, you can index the array to get the second hash and then update the value by passing `"age"` as the key:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > h = [{"name"=>"Bob"}, {"age"=>"30"}]
 => [{"name"=>"Bob"}, {"age"=>"30"}] 
1.9.3p194 :002 > h[1]["age"] = 31
 => 31 
1.9.3p194 :003 > h
 => [{"name"=>"Bob"}, {"age"=>31}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
[{"name"=>"Bob"}, {"age"=>"30"}][1]["age"] = 31
```