# How to convert a 2D array to a value object in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, object

I have a 2D array:

```
a = [["john doe", "01/03/2017", "01/04/2017", "event"], ["jane doe", "01/05/2017", "01/06/2017", "event"]...]
```

I would like to convert it to a value object in ruby. I found how to do it with a hash [Ruby / Replace value in array of hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421376/ruby-replace-value-in-array-of-hash) in the second answer of this question but not a 2D array. I would like to assign the value at `a[0][0]` to an attribute named `"name"`, `a[0][1]` to `"date1"`, `a[0][2]` to `"date2"` and `a[0][3]` to `"event"`.

This is something like what I'd like to accomplish although it is not complete and I dont know how to assign multiple indexes to the different attributes in one loop:

```
class Schedule_info
   arrt_accessor :name, :date1, :date2, :event

   def initialize arr
       #I would like this loop to contain all 4 attr assignments
       arr.each {|i| instance_variable_set(:name, i[0])}
```

Comment: do you mean you want to convert this array of arrays to an array of objects with name, date, etc methods?  so that after the conversion you'd be able to do a[0].name, a[1].event, etc?

Comment: I ultimately want to do something similar to this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421376/ruby-replace-value-in-array-of-hash) but with my 2D array

Comment: Could someone provide a reason to why I'm getting down voted.

Comment: it's not clear from your question exactly what you want. could you give us a sample output value you would like? or a sample data structure?

Comment: you also haven't shown any personal attempt at doing this before asking us. you're more likely to get up-voted if you can show some attempt you've made that isn't working.

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide an example of what I am trying to accomplish as well as a more detailed explanation

Comment: so once you create one of these schedule_info objects, you would access an item like this? `schedule_info.name[0]` is "john doe" and `schedule_info.name[1]` is "jane doe"

Comment: Yep I mainly wanted to know how to assign all 4 of the inner indexes to their corresponding attributes in one loop

Comment: let me know if my answer does what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be short and clean enough, without unneeded metaprogramming :

```
data = [["john doe", "01/03/2017", "01/04/2017", "event"],
        ["jane doe", "01/05/2017", "01/06/2017", "event"]]

class ScheduleInfo
  attr_reader :name, :date1, :date2, :type

  def initialize(*params)
    @name, @date1, @date2, @type = params
  end

  def to_s
    format('%s for %s between %s and %s', type, name, date1, date2)
  end
end

p info = ScheduleInfo.new('jane', '31/03/2017', '01/04/2017', 'party')
# #<ScheduleInfo:0x00000000d854a0 @name="jane", @date1="31/03/2017", @date2="01/04/2017", @type="party">
puts info.name
# "jane"

schedule_infos = data.map{ |params| ScheduleInfo.new(*params) }
puts schedule_infos
# event for john doe between 01/03/2017 and 01/04/2017
# event for jane doe between 01/05/2017 and 01/06/2017
```

Comment: Instead of converting the hash values into a string could you make a loop that places all the hashes (key and value) into one array. So that it is an array of hashes.

Comment: @EXC3ll3NTrhyTHM: I don't convert the `ScheduleInfo` object to a string, I just use a string representation of this object. `schedule_infos` is an array of `ScheduleInfo` objects, you can call `name`, `date1`, ... on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store the key value pairs in array index. Either you need to just remember that first index of array is gonna have "name" and assign `a[0][0] = "foo"` or just use array of hashes for the key value functionality you want to have

```
2.3.0 :006 > a = []
 => [] 
2.3.0 :007 > hash1 = {name: "hash1name", date: "hash1date", event: "hash1event"}
 => {:name=>"hash1name", :date=>"hash1date", :event=>"hash1event"} 
2.3.0 :008 > a << hash1
 => [{:name=>"hash1name", :date=>"hash1date", :event=>"hash1event"}] 
2.3.0 :009 > hash2 = {name: "hash2name", date: "hash2date", event: "hash2event"}
 => {:name=>"hash2name", :date=>"hash2date", :event=>"hash2event"} 
2.3.0 :010 > a << hash2
 => [{:name=>"hash1name", :date=>"hash1date", :event=>"hash1event"}, {:name=>"hash2name", :date=>"hash2date", :event=>"hash2event"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to call the attribute accessor method that corresponds to each array value.  You use `send` to call methods programmatically.  So you need an array of the method names that corresponds to the values you have in your given array.  Now, assuming the class with your attributes is called `Data`.

```
attrs = [:name, :date1, :date2, :event]
result = a.map do |e|
  d = Data.new
  e.each.with_index do |v, i|
    d.send(attrs[i], v)
  end
  d
end
```

The value `result` is an array of `Data` objects populated from your given array.

Of course, if you control the definition of your `Data` object, the best things would be to give it an initialize method that takes an array of values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Schedule_info
  arrt_accessor :name, :date1, :date2, :event

  def initialize arr
    @name = []
    @date1 = []
    @date2 = []
    @event = []
    arr.each |i| do
      name << i[0]
      date1 << i[1]
      date2 << i[2]
      event << i[3]
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: This accomplished the attribute assignment I was trying to figure out

Comment: @EXC3ll3NTrhyTHM glad to hear it! if this fully answered your question, please mark it as an accepted answer (by pressing the check) so other users will be able to find it. thank you!